# confused how Maven works(after pom deleted still works)

Tags: java, android, maven, guava

i created a Android project.And used the guava class just like this inside onCreate()

```
Multimap multimap;
```

Then it shows error as there was no library for `guava`.So i converted this to Maven project and added the dependency like this inside pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>14.0-rc3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So it is now available and error gone.Now i disable the maven nature of the project by going to the option

```
right click-->maven-->disable maven nature
```

Then i deleted pom.xml and also i delete guava folder from inside `.m2/com/google`.And also i deleted the my project name folder which was inside `.m2/repository`.So now as i guess

```
Multimap multimap;
```

and it's import line should show error.But it is still working without showing error.I deleted gen and rebuild and i deleted bin and rebuild.Still the project is working fine but it should not.Any idea guys why my project is not working.

Comment: check your local repository tag in your maven settings xml, may be its pointing to a different location and your jar are downloaded to that location.

Comment: Are you sure, that you've deleted the right `pom.xml`? Maven does not work if it can't find a `pom.xml` in the directory.

Comment: @SajanChandran no it's pointing to my .m2/repository only.As i have mentioned in my question also i deleted the project folder from that folder only.

Comment: @flash yes man.i am damn sure.I delete from eclipse.So less likely to delete wrong pom.

Comment: Then cntrl+click on your `Multimap` class see where it goes and check from which jar is coming and where, it will give you an idea.

Comment: @SajanChandran thanks.good suggestion.But when i am clicking ctrl, it's not showing the link so that i can go to that file.But when i am converting it to maven, it's showing inside m2/..../guava/...

Comment: I think then it could be eclipse playing some trick, just do a complete clean and rebuild of your project, try to add other classes from guava package.

Comment: @SajanChandran i think my eclipse fall in love with any other female eclipse  because i wrote Chdjshkahdha ch;.It is not showing error.Tried build.Restart eclipse.Still it's not shhowing any error.

Comment: The project is damaged and formed as raw folders/files in Eclipse, you need detach it from eclipse and re-import it to restore it back to a working state.